# How to set drawable as a background to image in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to set a drawable resource as a background to an `Image` in Jetpack compose?

Corresponding view XML code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_black_circle"
    android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
    ... 
/>
```

My current code,

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_logo),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(160.dp)
        .width(160.dp)
        .padding(32.dp),
)
```

`Modifier.background()` gives me the option to use color as a background.
Similarly looking for a way to use a drawable resource as a background.

**Note:**
Looking for a way to have the background in the image.
Not looking for enclosing the image inside another composable with the background.

Comment: What is drawable_black_circle? May be there is another way in compose. Can you post a screen of the final AppCompatImageView?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, This is just a sample drawable. 
I am trying to find if there is a composable existing which accepts a source drawable and a background drawable. I am aware that a custom drawable can be created to do this.

Comment: No there isn't,  but there are many ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With Jetpack compose, it is easy to draw a circle background or any shapes by using shape
Solution 1:

```
Image(painterResource(id = R.drawable.avatar1), contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.size(160.dp).background(
            color = Color.Black,
            shape = CircleShape
        )
            )
```

Solution 2:
In the case, you want to use a background image, you can use :

> **Modifier.paint**

For your case:

```
Image(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_logo),
    contentDescription = null,
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(160.dp)
        .width(160.dp)
        .paint(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.drawable_black_circle),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
        .padding(32.dp),
)
```

For other layouts, we can do the same. Here is an example for ConstraintLayout

```
ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .paint(painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_background_detail), contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth)
    ) {

    }
```

Answer (score 42):

***Set background image in jetpack compose***

```
fun MainViews(){
  Box(
    modifier = with (Modifier){
      fillMaxSize()
        .paint(
           // Replace with your image id 
           painterResource(id = R.drawable.image),
           contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds) 

})
{
  // Add more views here!
  Text("Hello Stack!")
}}
```

Note: I wrote this code on my Android phone maybe you got some syntax errors

Comment: I would actually recommend this.

Comment: Totally agree. This is correct answer at current date

Comment: use "ContentScale.FillBounds" instead of "ContentScale.fillBounds"

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

You can place two images in a `Box`, so main one will be on top of the background.

If you are going to use such view extensively, you can create your own composable which can be used simply like this:

```kotlin
ImageWithBackground(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.app_logo),
    backgroundDrawableResId = R.drawable.background,
    contentDescription = "",
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(160.dp)
        .width(160.dp)
        .padding(32.dp),
)
```

Composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ImageWithBackground(
    painter: Painter,
    @DrawableRes backgroundDrawableResId: Int,
    contentDescription: String?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    alignment: Alignment = Alignment.Center,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    alpha: Float = DefaultAlpha,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(backgroundDrawableResId),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
        )
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = contentDescription,
            alignment = alignment,
            contentScale = contentScale,
            alpha = alpha,
            colorFilter = colorFilter,
            modifier = Modifier
                .matchParentSize()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already aware of this method. As mentioned in the question, "Not looking for enclosing the image inside another composable with the background.". I am trying to achieve this using a single composable. Having a Box and Two Images seems too much code for such a simple requirement which apparently has a simple code in Views. 
P.S: The drawable name was for example.

Comment: @Abhimanyu I see. There's no builtin solution, but check out updated answer on how you can use it easily in your app

Answer (score 1):

Sir if you absolutely do not wish to nest the image inside another, you could build it using `Canvas`. However, I don't see a problem here since under the hood, that's what it is — an image on top of another. A `Box` is just a positioning mechanism. If your decide to go for `Canvas`, this is how to go about using it:

```
val backgroundVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
val backgroundPainter = rememberVectorPainter(image = backgroundVector)

val foregroundVector = ... // Same as above
val foregroundPainter = rememberVectorPainter(...) // Same as above

Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    with(backgroundPainter) {
        draw(painter.intrinsicSize) // You can scale and modify, all the good stuff
    }
    with(foregroundPainter) {
        // Ditto as above,
    }
}
```

There's also the `transform` scope available, or the individual `translate`, `rotate`, and `scale`, maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a flexible solution to have a changeable height(i.e. with a minHeight modifier), so I prepared a solution that relies on the content in the box and adjusts the background image size.

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .defaultMinSize(
                minHeight = 150.dp // we have a min height for the container, it's flexible
            )
            .background(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 4.dp)
            ),
    ) {

        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val minLoyaltyCardHeight = 150.dp

        var contentHeightDp by remember { mutableStateOf(minLoyaltyCardHeight) }


        Image( // image with flexible height as a background
            modifier = Modifier.height(contentHeightDp),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.paper_texture),
            contentDescription = "paper_texture",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        )

        Column( //main content
            modifier = Modifier
            .onGloballyPositioned { // responsible for measuring the main content
                contentHeightDp = density.run { it.size.height.toDp().coerceAtLeast(minLoyaltyCardHeight) }
            }
            .padding(all = 16.dp)       
        ) {
           ...
        }
```